# Looking for web based ticketing system with specific e-mail interface requirements

Tags: web-apps, email, project-management, support-tracker

I am look for a web based ticketing system that uses IMAP to interface with our e-mail service (Google) and has the ability to change what e-mail address the tickets gets responded with. We have two e-mail addresses, one for internal requests, and one for customer issues, and we like to toggle between the two in case we have to respond to a customer from an internally forwarded issue. Also must have good statistic reporting.

We're currently using FogBugz which handles e-mail great, but falls down on reporting (fairly nonexistent and complicated to do what we want) and isn't great for multiple responders.

We tried Zendesk, but didn't like the fact that it used an e-mail forwarder instead of IMAP. We hated that users would see careerssupport-zendesk-16548@zendesk.com (this is a made up example) as the contact email.

Fogbugz and Salesforce integration would be pluses.